# Is using a lot of AngularJS and JavaScript a bad practice for a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developing a huge project. The project is a webshop where most of the things are dynamically. Because of this, I decided to use `AngularJS` as a framework and added the `jQuery` library.

However, after developing more than 3 months now. I see that i got alot of `AngularJS` code.

**My angular structure is currently:**

- 34 controllers - All about **6kb** in size (non-minified, I can still save some space there)*
- 1 file with more then 21 angular services.  - **11KB** in size (non-minified)
- 1 file with 44 custom angular filters - **24KB** in size (non-minified)
- 1 file with 32 custom angular directives - **18KB** in size (non-minified)

**On top of this i also use:**

- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)
- Bootstrap
- jQuery
- [Typo.js](https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/)**
- [Tablesaw](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw)

I did not  list every `AngularJS` or `jQuery` / `JavaScript` library I included inside the project. That would get a pretty long list, which would be unnessecary.

> *Not all controllers are loaded at once. Most controllers at one time is 5.
>   **When a word is misspelled it shows a word correction. Just like google.com. Also generates suggestions when a user searches for
>   something and no results were found. It shows equivalent word
>   suggestions that *have* results.

The project makes alot of AJAX calls using the `$http` service from `AngularJS`. Eg; *auto complete* in the search, *pages*, *user information*, *basket data* .. and much *more*.

The benefit of it in my eyes: 'It feels very smooth'. All data gets loaded within the same page if it is part of the same page.

For example:

The webshop articles are loaded on the page **/assortment/**. When searching, the search results are displayed on the **same page**, instead of redirecting to a **/search/** page.

**My question is:**

Is using so much `JavaScript` a bad practice? Does this affect slower computers alot? or is the difference not noticable? Or do i have to improve the code, so it won't affect slower PC's?

I go to mention that I am not able to test it on different computers yet. So i do not know how it performs on other PC's.

I found 1 topic on SO with a similair question: [What's the downside of using too much JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524659/whats-the-downside-of-using-too-much-javascript)

But the question itself is more directing to; *'using libraries'*

Comment: The files you listed are pretty small, and realize that most JS files, once loaded, are cached, and the browser will return a 302 when found in the cache, instead of 200 meaning it loaded from the server OK.  So usually in an app, even if you have 1MB in script, it should get cached and thus you don't have a recurring network hit.

Comment: This is *not* by any means what I would consider a "lot" of javascript.  Seems quite light on js to me.

Comment: Just a side note: be wary using jquery along side Angular. Remember angular has JQlite integrated anyway, and it can sometimes lead developers unfamiliar with the "angular way of doing things" to use it as a crutch

Comment: Consider a "popular" (though whether good or not is left to the reader...) library such as Kendo UI is over 2Mb minified.

Comment: Being concerned about not even 100kB non-minified in this day and age seems a bit odd. A random website i host shows half a dozen high resolution images on the front page which is absurdly more data than that.

Comment: @freemn-m Currently it is not as much indeed. But there will come alot more.

Comment: *eyes own website with 300kb of javascript on intense page*. I wouldn't worry if I were you.

Comment: @Red we can only go on the information provided - no-where in your question have you said that the amount of js will increase by an order of magnitude (eg 1000x more).  (which makes listing any amount somewhat pointless).

Comment: @ASDFGerte The totall amount in MB is currently 4.6MB. But i guess this still is not much these days.

Comment: @Anduril Yes angular has jQlite, it will however use jQuery if available. jQuery has more functions to use than jQlite. But i need to digg into it to find out any pros and cons :)

Comment: @Red I know it will, just a friendly message from someone that has travelled a similar road :-) There is very little that you need jquery for inside angular and modifying the DOM using jq outside the digest cycle can cause bugs and issues that can be tricky to track down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's 2017. There is no such thing as too much JavaScript. Maybe if someone is trying to access your site from a device that came out in the early 2000s, then they should rather get a new device.

We have the technology, so let's use it.

Comment: Yes, i though the same things. Wanted to be sure. But seems like everyone agrees on this. Thanks for you awnser.